# Iterating Over Rows in Python Array to Extract Column Data

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, loops

I am using Python and looking to iterate through each row of an Nx9 array and extract certain values from the row to form another matrix with them. The N value can change depending on the file I am reading but I have used N=3 in my example. I only require the 0th, 1st, 3rd and 4th values of each row to form into an array which I need to store. E.g:

```
result = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
                  [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
                  [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]])

#Output matrix of first row should be: ([[1,2],[4,5]])
#Output matrix of second row should be: ([[11,12],[14,15]])
#Output matrix of third row should be: ([[21,22],[24,25]])
```

I should then end up with N number of matrices formed with the extracted values - a 2D matrix for each row. However, the matrices formed appear 3D so when transposed and subtracted I receive the error `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,2,3) (3,2,2)`. I am aware that a (3,2,2) matrix cannot be subtracted from a (2,2,3) so how do I obtain a 2D matrix N number of times? Would a loop be better suited? Any suggestions?

```py
import numpy as np

result = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
                   [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
                   [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]])

a = result[:, 0]
b = result[:, 1]
c = result[:, 2]
d = result[:, 3]
e = result[:, 4]
f = result[:, 5]
g = result[:, 6]
h = result[:, 7]
i = result[:, 8]
output = [[a, b], [d, e]]
output = np.array(output)
output_transpose = output.transpose()
result = 0.5 * (output - output_transpose)
```

Comment: can you show us how this is supposed to look like mathematically? Because it's pretty obvious you can't subtract a (2,2,3) Matrix from a (3,2,2). I think your matrices need to be, I guess, palindromic in their shapes for that to work. And (2,2,3) read in reverse is not the same. It's (3,2,2) so your general formula a*M*M^-1 can only work on matrices who's shapes are palindromic.

Comment: Please share the entire error message.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [276]: result = np.array( 
     ...:     [ 
     ...:         [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 
     ...:         [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19], 
     ...:         [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29], 
     ...:     ] 
     ...: ) 
     ...:  
     ...: a = result[:, 0] 
          ...
     ...: i = result[:, 8] 
     ...: output = [[a, b], [d, e]]                                                            
In [277]: output                                                                               
Out[277]: 
[[array([ 1, 11, 21]), array([ 2, 12, 22])],
 [array([ 4, 14, 24]), array([ 5, 15, 25])]]
In [278]: arr = np.array(output)                                                               
In [279]: arr                                                                                  
Out[279]: 
array([[[ 1, 11, 21],
        [ 2, 12, 22]],

       [[ 4, 14, 24],
        [ 5, 15, 25]]])
In [280]: arr.shape                                                                            
Out[280]: (2, 2, 3)
In [281]: arr.T.shape                                                                          
Out[281]: (3, 2, 2)
```

`transpose` exchanges the 1st and last dimensions.

A cleaner way to make a (N,2,2) array from selected columns is:

```
In [282]: arr = result[:,[0,1,3,4]].reshape(3,2,2)                                             
In [283]: arr.shape                                                                            
Out[283]: (3, 2, 2)
In [284]: arr                                                                                  
Out[284]: 
array([[[ 1,  2],
        [ 4,  5]],

       [[11, 12],
        [14, 15]],

       [[21, 22],
        [24, 25]]])
```

Since the last 2 dimensions are 2, you could transpose them, and take the difference:

```
In [285]: arr-arr.transpose(0,2,1)                                                             
Out[285]: 
array([[[ 0, -2],
        [ 2,  0]],

       [[ 0, -2],
        [ 2,  0]],

       [[ 0, -2],
        [ 2,  0]]])
```

Another way to get the (N,2,2) array is with a matrix index:

```
In [286]: result[:,[[0,1],[3,4]]]                                                              
Out[286]: 
array([[[ 1,  2],
        [ 4,  5]],

       [[11, 12],
        [14, 15]],

       [[21, 22],
        [24, 25]]])
```

Answer (score -1):

Ok, this is not a coding problem, but a math problem. I wrote some code for you, since it's pretty obvious you're a beginner, so there will be some unfamiliar syntax in there that you should look into so you can avoid problems like this in the future. You might not use them all that often, but it's good to know how to do it, because it expands your understanding of python syntax in general.

First up, the complete code for easy copy and pasting:

```py
import numpy as np

result=np.array([[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
                 [11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19],
                 [21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29]])

output = np.array(tuple(result[:,i] for i in (0,1,3)))


def Matrix_Operation(Matrix,Coefficient):

    if (Matrix.shape == Matrix.shape[::-1] 
        and isinstance(Matrix,np.ndarray)
        and isinstance(Coefficient,float)):

        return Coefficient*(Matrix-Matrix.transpose())
    else:
        print('The shape of you Matrix is not palindromic')
        print('You cannot substitute matrices of unequal shape')
        print('Your shape: %s'%str(Matrix.shape))

print(Matrix_Operation(output,0.5))
```

Now let's talk about a step by step explanation of what's happening here:

```py
import numpy as np

result=np.array([[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
                 [11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19],
                 [21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29]])
```

Python uses indentation (alignment of whitespaces) as an integral part of it's syntax. However, if you provide brackets, a lot of the time you don't need aligning indentations in order for the interpreter to understand your code. If you provide a large array of values manually, it is usually adviseable to start new lines at the commas (here, the commas separating the sublists). It's just more readable and that way your data isn't off screen in your coding program.

```py
output = np.array(tuple(result[:,i] for i in (0,1,3)))
```

List comprehensions are a big deal in python and really handy for dirty one liners. As far as I know, no other language gives you this option. That's one of the reasons why python is so great. I basically created a list of lists, where each sublist is result[:,i] for every i in (0,1,3). This is cast as a tuple (yes, list comprehensions can also be done with tuples, not just lists). Finally I wrapped it in the np.array function, since this is the type required for our mathematical operations later on.

```py
def Matrix_Operation(Matrix,Coefficient):

    if (Matrix.shape == Matrix.shape[::-1] 
        and isinstance(Matrix,np.ndarray)
        and isinstance(Coefficient,(float,int))):

        return Coefficient*(Matrix-Matrix.transpose())
    else:
        print('The shape of you Matrix is not palindromic')
        print('You cannot substitute matrices of unequal shape')
        print('Your shape: %s'%str(Matrix.shape))

print(Matrix_Operation(output,0.5))
```

If you're gonna create a complex formula in python code, why not wrap it inside an abstractable function? You can incorporate a lot of "quality control" into a function as well, to check if it is given the correct input for the task it is supposed to do.

Your code failed, because you were trying to subtract a (2,2,3) shaped matrix from a (3,2,2) matrix. So we'll need a code snippet to check, if our provided matrix has a palindromic shape. You can reverse the order of items in a container by doing `Container[::-1]` and so we ask, if Matrix.shape == Matrix.shape[::-1]. Further, it is necessary, that our Matrix is a `np.ndarray` and if our coefficient is a number. That's what I'm doing with the `isinstance()` function. You can check for multiple types at once, which is why the `isinstance(Coefficient,(float,int))` contains a tuple with both int and float in it.

Now that we have ensured that our input makes sense, we can preform our Matrix_Operation.
So in conclusion: Check if your math is solid before asking SO for help, because people here can get pretty annoyed at that sort of thing. You probably noticed by now that someone has already downvoted your question. Personally, I believe it's necessary to let newbies ask a couple stupid questions before they get into the groove, but that's what the voting button is for, I guess.

Comment: Thanks for the reply I appreciate the help. I will edit my question slightly as I believe the way I have asked it is confusing.